# Build Failed Nativescript with error of metadata

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I have hybrid app with NativeScript and upgraded the Angular version from 14 to 16.2. When I take iOS build I am getting this below error.
When I try to run the build I am getting below message:

```
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Building project...
Xcode build...
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/gayathri/Projects/apps/abc/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-x86_64.bin'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'nativescriptabc' from project 'nativescriptabc')
note: Using codesigning identity override: 
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Stale file '/Users/gayathri/Projects/apps/abc/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/855410917916202301/nativescriptabc-Prefix.pch.gch' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

warning: Run script build phase 'NativeScript PreBuild' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'nativescriptabc' from project 'nativescriptabc').
```

And My package.json is below

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "16.2.2",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~7.0.0",
    "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext": "^8.0.2",
    "@nx/angular": "14.3.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "nativescript-insomnia": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "~7.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.2.2",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.3.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.4.1",
    "@nativescript/eslint-plugin": "~0.0.4",
    "@nativescript/nx": "^4.0.1",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^16.2.0",
    "@nstudio/angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/web": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/web-angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nx/angular": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/cypress": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/jest": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/js": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/linter": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/workspace": "16.7.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "16.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "29.4.4",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.62.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.14.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.9.2",
    "ng-packagr": "16.2.1",
    "nx": "16.7.4",
    "nx-cloud": "16.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "~14.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "~7.5.0",
    "postcss-url": "~10.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
```

Any help on this?